# PTIJ: Superman can carry the Batmobile on Shabbat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

On Shabbat, Superman saw the Batmobile was stuck in a narrow alley (more than 3-handbreaths wide) between the Daily Planet and Wayne Enterprises. In order to carry the Batmobile out of the alley, could Superman  make a "beam" of light with his laser vision establishing a "Closed Lane"?

[https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935238/jewish/Shabbat-Chapter-Seventeen.htm]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Someone already built this http://elliottmalkin.com/laser/

Comment: Non-Purim-Torah: Is the Batmobile muktzah? There's actually serious conversation about whether a gun is muktzah. What is its "normal use"? Some argue the point of a gun is so would-be "bad guys" see it and don't do bad stuff, so the gun is mostly used while not being fired. In which case -- is the Batmobile a stealthy means of Batman transportation, or is it intended to visibly intimidate the cowardly and superstitious? Depends on which interpretation of Batman you follow.

Comment: Surely Batman has a telescoping *Lechi* in his utility belt ...

Comment: In this scenario, is the batmobile needed for pikuach nefesh purposes, or does Batman just wish to have it parked elsewhere?

Comment: @Josh K - Yes, pikuach nefesh purposes : Batman was trapped under the Batmobile.

Comment: Well,  @חידה,  you don't need super powers to know that even d'orayta melacha is mutar on Shabbat in pikuach nefesh situations!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Heat vision in Kryptonians][1] is a release of stored solar energy from the eyes. As such, it is not igniting a fire from scratch. Further, since it is a superpower Kryptonians have from a yellow sun such as ours, it is considered toldat chama, so any bishul concerns would be obviated.

However, since people don't realize its origin, and because of what it is, there is a concern of literal *maris ayin*. Granted that this isn't happening in a narrow alleyway, rather than in a reshus harabim, but perhaps we hold maris ayin applies even in private.

The better approach would be to simply toss the car out of the alley, because reshus harabim higher than 10 tefachim counts as a mekom petur. As Rambam writes in [perush hamishnayos][2]:

> דע כי רשות הרבים מגיע עד עשרה טפחים, ולמעלה מעשרה טפחים ברשות הרבים הוא מקום פטור.

> והמחלוקת ביניהם הוא, כי הזורק דבר מרשות היחיד לרשות היחיד, ועבר על רשות הרבים, רבי עקיבא אומר, כי אם עבר אותו החפץ שזרק על אויר רשות הרבים בתוך עשרה, שהוא כאילו נח, ורבנן אינן אומרים כן. אבל אם זרק למעלה מעשרה, אפילו רבי עקיבא פוטר.

> והלכה כחכמים:

[1]: [https://superman.fandom.com/wiki/Heat_Vision#:~:text=Heat%20Vision%20is%20a%20superpower,as%20infra%2Dred%20light](https://superman.fandom.com/wiki/Heat_Vision#:%7E:text=Heat%20Vision%20is%20a%20superpower,as%20infra%2Dred%20light)).
[2]: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%90

Comment: Excellent Kal-el Halacha!